# Getting attachments of a S/MIME signed mail

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the attachments of a signed mail via the microsoft-graph-api.

I use a **GET-Request** on this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkAG.../attachments
```

This should return a list of objects for the specified mail. Every object contains metadata like "**name**" and "**contentType**" of one attachment as well as the attribute "**contentBytes**" which contains the content of the attachment as a `base64-string`.

If the mail has no attachments this list is empty.

This works fine so far with every mail that is not signed via `S/MIME`.
However, if the mail is signed with `S/MIME`, I get strange results in the response list.

No matter how many attachments the mail has, the response list only contains one element. This element then comes with the name "**smime.p7m**" and the contentType "**multipart/signed**" while the contentBytes attribute contains almost the entire MIME of the mail instead of the content of a single attachment.

I can't imagine that this is desired behaviour, so I'm asking:

**Is this a bug in the microsoft-graph-api or am I doing something wrong in the request and if so, how can I fix this?**

Comment: Hi @Maxelhead. Did you manage to write the code? I have same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug but the expected behavior in case of a 'multipart/signed' message.

From [RFC5751](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5751.txt) (bottom of page 26):

> The multipart/signed media type has two parts.  The first part
>      contains the MIME entity that is signed; the second part contains the
>      "detached signature" CMS SignedData object in which the
>      encapContentInfo eContent field is absent.

So the signed content, including any attachments, is stored inside the one smime.p7m attachment. It is up to you to extract it.

Assuming you are using .Net, you can use the [SignedCms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to validate the signature and retrieve the content using the ContentInfo property.

Comment: What is the code to extract attachments from `application/pkcs7-mime` attachment. Outlook shows pdf and xml.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a bit unrelated to your question but I spent last 3 days trying extract attachments from *signed but unencrypted email*. Hope this helps someone in similar situation. **Here are steps which worked for me in vb.net:**

1. Install [Mimekit Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeKit/)
2. Correctly identify the S/Mime signed email by looking at its content type and attachment name (S/Mime signed emails always have smime.p7m file attached to it)

```
If String.Equals(origMessage.Attachments.First.ContentType, "multipart/signed", 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) AndAlso
String.Equals(origMessage.Attachments.First.Name, "smime.p7m", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
```

3. Load smime file as EWS FileAttachment and create new memoryStream out of it. Then create MimeKit.MimeEntity of this stream. Now you're using MimeKit library which is great for this stuff

```
Dim smimeFile As FileAttachment = origMessage.Attachments.First
smimeFile.Load()
Dim memoryStreamSigned As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(smimeFile.Content)
Dim entity = MimeEntity.Load(memoryStreamSigned)
```

4. Iterate over your MimeEntity instance for all attachments

```
If TypeOf entity Is Cryptography.MultipartSigned Then
    Dim mltipart As Multipart = entity
    Dim attachments As MimeEntity = mltipart(0)
    If TypeOf attachments Is Multipart Then
        Dim mltipartAttachments As Multipart = attachments
        For i As Integer = 0 To mltipartAttachments.Count - 1
            If mltipartAttachments(i).IsAttachment Then
                **'BOOM, now you're looping your attachment files one by one**
                **'Call your decode function to read your attachment as array of Bytes**
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
```

5. Read your attachment as array of Bytes. Do this inside the for of previous step.

```
'Read and decode content stream
Dim fileStrm = New MemoryStream()
mltipartAttachments(i).Content.DecodeTo(fileStrm)

Dim decodedBytes(0 To fileStrm.Length - 1) As Byte
fileStrm.Position = 0  'This is important because .DecodeTo set the position to the end!!
fileStrm.Read(decodedBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileStrm.Length))
```

**Now you have your attachment file decoded as an array of Bytes and you can just save it or do whatever you want :)** Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug but the expected behavior in case of a 'multipart/signed' message.

To add helpful information, you need to extract the file **smime.p7m** which is base64 encoded. After decoding the file, you will get a plain MIME file.

This file then contains 3 elements:

1. The mail validation signature.
2. The attachments separated one by one, according to a MIME specification, being easy to be retrieved because you get also the file name and content type for each attachment.
3. The Certificate and Certificate Chain for the signer.

You can get the clean mime content with these commands:

**openssl smime -verify -noverify -in smime.p7m -inform DER -out content.mime**

or

**openssl smime -verify -noverify -in smime.p7m -out content.mime**