# How to extract attachment from application/pkcs7-mime received from Microsoft Graph API in .NET Core

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am downloading attachments with Microsoft Graph API in .NET Core 3.1.

```
await client.Users[mail.OwnerEmail].Messages[mail.Id].Attachments.Request().GetAsync()
```

Recently one email had strange attachment with content type `application/pkcs7-mime` (extension .p7m). I need to extract attachments inside this signed attachment. Outlook shows 2 attachments for this mail: `pdf` and `xml`. I need these 2 files.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961935/getting-attachments-of-a-s-mime-signed-mail/56127763#56127763) thread, but I don't understand the answer.

I tried:

```
var signed = new SignedCms();
signed.Decode(signedAttachment.Content);   //Exception: ASN1 corrupted data.
```

and

```
new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(signedAttachment.Content))
```

and receive some friendly name and version:

[image: debugger screenshot]

but I don't know how to extract attachments.

Edited:

Also tried:

```
var envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms();
envelopedCms.Decode(signedAttachment.Content);
```

and `Decrypt` ... Nothing.